# What is a "stable complex"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it have anything to do with a complex for horses? Google couldn't help me.

> "This Arizona compound includes a main house, two guest houses, **a stable complex**, an outdoor patio, an in-ground pool and a helipad. Overall, there are 10 bedrooms and 12 full bathrooms."

Source: [The  Obamas just bought an $8.1 million mansion - here's what $8 million will get you around the country](http://www.cnbc.com/2017/06/12/how-much-house-you-can-buy-for-8-million-across-america.html).

Comment: Not too shabby for only 37 times the price of the average house.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase

> a stable complex

means

> accommodation and facilities for many horses

Comment: I suppose it means something fancier than **stables**. Maybe it has a horse hot tub.

Comment: It means stables, outdoor pens and rings.

Comment: @Lambie: How do you know rings are involved?

Comment: We won't know that without looking at the property brochure. I used the word "facilities" as a catch-all.

Comment: Fancy stables etc, might include outdoor  pens and riding rings. It's more than just a stable.